# azure service principal : access denied in jenkins pipeline fine in command line (with plugin or not)

Tags: azure, authentication, jenkins, plugins

I created a freestyle project in Jenkins where I tried to log in azure in a groovy file

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy

// Jenkinsfile (Declarative Pipeline)

pipeline {
  agent any



  stages {
    stage('Stage') {
      steps{
          script {
            withCredentials([azureServicePrincipal('withplugin')]) {
            
              sh 'az login --service-principal -u $AZURE_CLIENT_ID -p $AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET -t $AZURE_TENANT_ID'
              sh 'az account set -s $AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID'        
          }
         }
      }
    }

  }
}
```

I created the service principal, I can login with  "AZ" "sh AZ" "nohup sh AZ"
command line but in Jenkins with or without plugin with clear credential or variable

access is denied in my console output

- az login --service-principal -u **** -p ****-t ****

> Access is denied.

I tried 2 days back to basics even nothing work ....

Can anyone could help me out ?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to just add an Azure service principal to Jenkins credential and then write an Jenkins pipeline script by having **'withCredentials([azureServicePrincipal('SERVICEPRINCIPALCREDENTIALID')])'** and then using 'sh' part to have Azure CLI commands. For more information with regards to it, please refer [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/jenkins/deploy-to-azure-app-service-using-azure-cli#add-azure-service-principal-to-jenkins-credential) Azure document or [this](https://plugins.jenkins.io/azure-credentials/) Jenkins plugin article or [this](https://www.jenkins.io/blog/2017/08/10/kubernetes-with-pipeline-acs/%5C) Jenkins blog.

Source or Related references:

- [Jenkins azure deploy error: az login error issuer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60761033/)
- [use Azure Batch as Jenkins' node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55788323/)
- [How to use Jenkins to upload to Azure Data Lake Storage Gen1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55263249/)
- [Jenkins Active Choices Parameter with Docker to get Azure tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54233150/)
- [Azure provisioning with Jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54463106/)

Comment: Hello Krishna , This is what i did ...  the withplugin is the name I gave to my jenkins records

Comment: Indeed , I think it's more a json conversion issue